# How to get "C" written frameworks' headers?

Tags: iphone, iphone-privateapi

I have a question for those iPhone hackers.

People using private apis know that their private headers are dumped using a tool called 'class-dump'. As I know, this tool only dumps Objective-C headers. Is there any way to dump C headers?

For example, GraphicsService, a framework on iPhone. Some guys successfully generated its headers. How did they do it? I think the possible way is to dump the headers with the symbols' names. But how to get them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'otool' to inspect libraries. You'll also find that the Eclipse CDT viewer can inspect and open libraries as well, which may be able to give you what you need.